# Simple sql query to get value for a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple problem in SQL. I have a table with 4 columns. Columns being ID, DateTime, Decimal, AnotherID.

```
DECLARE @data DATETIME 
SET @data = '20120101'

SELECT [ID]
      ,[Data]
      ,[Value]
      ,[InID]   
 FROM [dbo].[Static] 
 WHERE InID = 1 AND [Data] <= @data
```

Now I have to choose proper Value based on InID and Data. InID can have multiple rows with different dates. This is example output for InID = 1.

```
ID          Data            Value              InID
389         2012-01-02      10.00000000     1
390         2011-12-16      20.00000000     1
391         2011-12-13      15.00000000     1
```

Now based on `InID` and `Data` I need to get `Value` for given date. For example for `InID = 1` I need to get `Value` for day `2011-12-14`. Of course the value should be taken from `13th of December` and if I ask it about value for date `2012-01-13` it should take last value. However in case the question is about date before the first date it should return `NULL`. I tried multiple combinations but my brain seems to be out of order atm so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will work fine for 13th.. but not for 2012-01-03 or 17th. I need one value.. not multple ones.

Comment: With your sample data, you say that passing in `2011-12-12` should yield NULL? Yet your comments to answer say it should be the nearest date?  *(Which would be `2011-12-13`?)*

Comment: well nearest date down... not nearest date up. For 2011-12-12 it should be null since there's no date before it. For date 2012-01-01 it should take 2011-12-16 date and not 2012-01-02.

Comment: Wait, it changed again?  `nearest date down`?  For your sample data please tell me what the results should be for these dates?  (`2011-12-12`, `2011-12-13`, `2011-12-14`, `2011-12-15`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get only the most recent `Value` constrained by the `@data` parameter:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
FROM [dbo].[Static] 
WHERE InID = 1 AND [Data] <= @data
ORDER BY [Data] DESC;
```

To the last part of your question if you need a `NULL` result you'll have to wrap the query above as it will return an empty result set if nothing qualifies:

```
DECLARE @theValue float;
SELECT @theValue = (
  SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
  FROM [dbo].[Static] 
  WHERE InID = 1 AND [Data] <= @data
  ORDER BY [Data] DESC
);
```

The **nearest** would be this (just be aware that it can grab either future or past dates):

```
 SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
 FROM [dbo].[Static]
 WHERE InID = 1
 ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(Day, [Data], @data));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how efficient this is, but it should work...

```
-- Some other commands here, that MUST be terminated with a ;
-- It's anal, but that's how MS implemented the WITH syntax

WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InID ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @yourDate, Data)) ASC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    static
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

**EDIT**

This is what I had originally...

It gives `The nearest date down`.

```
;WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InID ORDER BY Data DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    static
  WHERE
    Data <= @yourDate
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

Comment: Dems. For a date of 2012-01-17 it will return value for a date of 2011-12-13 and I need it to return 2012-01-02 on the nearest date possible.

Comment: I need to get 1 value per date. However it isn't as simple as doing TOP1 and taking first value, as it has to be relevant to current date. If I ask for todays date I should get answer from 2012-01-02 (Value of 10). If i ask for date 2012-01-01 I should get value of 20 (which will be in fact from date 2011-12-16.

Comment: @MadBoy **Try** either of these answers. They do **EXACTLY** what you're asking for!

Comment: `Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Comment: @MadBoy - My answer gives one row per InID.  And that row is the one with the *nearest* date to your `@yourDate` parameter.  Yuck's is simpler, giving the same row, but for a specific InID.

Comment: @MadBoy - Prefix WITH with a `;`

Comment: @Dems He might not be running a version of SQL Server that supports CTE.

Comment: @Dems And BTW, the reason the statements before `WITH` have to be terminated is because `WITH` can appear at the end of some queries with a different meaning. The parser could probably have figured out the usage, but it's good practice to end all statements with `;` anyway :)

Comment: @Dems it works now but it returns the closest date which also takes and per my comment I need to have it per nearest date "down". For date 2012-01-01 it should take 2011-12-16 date and not 2012-01-02. Right now for a date of 2012-01-01 it returns value from 2012-01-02.

Comment: I wasn't able to test it the first time as WITH wasn't working and before you mentioned ; you changed it to ABS (I guess nearest possible date comment was missing keyword `down`. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1
       [ID]
      ,[Data]
      ,[Value]
      ,[InID]   
 FROM [dbo].[Static] 
 WHERE InID = 1 AND [Data] <= @data
ORDER BY DATA desc
```

If the rows does not exists you wand NULLs in **all** the fields?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you all the values for the one row based on the highest qualified date record.  Only issue is if you have multiple entries on the same date with an "InID" = 1.  If the field for data is actually a date/time precision (just simplified for your posting sample), then you'll get even better precision.  I would ensure an index on InID and Data to optimize better.

```
select
      Static.*
   from
      ( select max( Data ) as HighestQualifiedDate
           from Static
          where InID = 1
            and Data <= @data ) PreQuery
      JOIN Static
         on InID = 1
         AND PreQuery.HighestQualifiedDate = Static.Data
```

Comment: I have maxinum one InID and Date. There's no way for users to add more Values for the same date for one InID.

Comment: This seems to be quite good the only thing is if my date exactly matches the one I want it will use the older one. For example asking about 2012-01-02 will give me result from 2011-12-16 but if I ask for 2012-01-03 it will give me proper result from 2012-01-02.

Comment: Hrmms I guess it's because of Time issue (as I have no 00:00:00 but some time. I'll reset the values to 00:00:00 and it should work!

Comment: @MadBoy, try setting your date to 2012-01-02 23:59:59, or change the query to LESS than the following day of 2012-01-03.

Comment: After more testing it does exactly how I want it to work. Thank you. I have updated dates to have 00:00:00 and it works perfect.

Comment: @MadBoy, glad it worked for you, but if so, did the other answer that you checked as the solution also work for you?  It didn't appear to from your other comments.

Comment: Well I tested some (and they changed their answers a lot) but right now from what I see every proposed solution works, even the simplest ones. I don't know why it wasn't working at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    [Value]
FROM
  ( SELECT TOP 1  
        [Data], [Value]
    FROM [dbo].[Static] 
    WHERE InID = 1 AND [Data] <= @data
    ORDER BY [Data] DESC
  UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1 
        [Data], [Value]
    FROM [dbo].[Static] 
    WHERE InID = 1 AND [Data] >= @data
    ORDER BY [Data] ASC
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(day, -1, MIN([Data])), NULL
    FROM [dbo].[Static] 
    WHERE InID = 1 
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(Day, [Data], @data))
```